# cocos2d Move Sprite using buttons

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, ccmenu

Using CCMenu I have create Two Buttons Up and Down  Here is the code

```
    CCSprite *normlUp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Up.png"];
    CCSprite *selectedUp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Up.png"];
    selectedUp.color = ccGREEN;

    CCMenuItemSprite *up = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:normlUp selectedSprite:selectedUp target:self selector:@selector(upItemTouched)];
    up.position = CGPointMake(-220, -115);

    CCSprite *normlDown = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Down.jpeg"];
    CCSprite *selectedDown = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Down.jpeg"];
    selectedDown.color = ccGREEN;

    CCMenuItemSprite *down = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:normlDown selectedSprite:selectedDown target:self selector:@selector(downItemTouched)];
    down.position = CGPointMake(-220,-140 );

    CCMenu *upDown = [CCMenu menuWithItems:up,down,nil];
    [self addChild:upDown z:4];
```

How to write upItemTouched and downItemTouched Methods
Also the sprite should move smoothly on the screen
I am New to cocos2d so please accept my simple questions........

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on what exactly do you want to happen when one of them is touched ?

Answer (score 0):

Use CCMenuItemSprite assigning adding selector to the sprite, so when you touch down/up sprite that selector method will be called.
so, when "up" is touched, set one boolean to true and when "down" is touched, set another boolean to true.

Now in update/tick method check which boolean in true and then move the sprite.

When done moving, in touchesEnded method just set those boolean to false.